# Simulink if-else block retains last value instead of switching back to 0

Tags: if-statement, state, action, simulink, multiple-conditions

First let me explain this system: this is one of a couple of states all based on 3 inputs. None work at the moment so I took this one apart to test it. This state is true if u1>0 & u2>20 & u3>40.
Which it is not due to u2<20 the first 5 seconds. Then it switches on, but doesn't switch off/go back to 0 when u1<0 at 8 seconds.

[All inputs and output of state and state conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADCve.png)

I have been at this problem for a while now but can't seem to think of a solution. I put my 'if action subsystem' on reset instead of hold but it will not switch off/reset to zero. I saw somewhere you can give it an initial condition (in my case 0) to switch back to, but I don't know where to put this, no further explanation was given on that. I took a screenshot of the whole system and the 3 inputs.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use the if block and if action subsystems? You could just use relational operator and a logical AND block to perform the same function.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments the if action subsystem seems to be an overkill. You can reproduce the logic using isequal blocks ('>') and a logical AND block ('AND').

Then i  noticed that the two enable subsystem (in transparency) look like this:
The else (false) condition contains a gain, the if (true) just passes the signal through. This is reproduced in the right part of the simulink with a switch block.

The total logic should behave like this:

if the 3 conditions u1>0,u2>20,u3>40 are all true, the output is u1.

if any of them is false (ex. u1<0), the output is 7*u1.

[image: proposal]